# Column subtotals and totals in sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: 2010, list-view, custom-list, view

I have a custom list

```
State , Name , Budget , Actual 
CA       Jon    10        8
CA       Jim     5        3

subtotal        15       11

AZ       Jane    15       9
AZ       Mike    20       11

sub total       25        20

Total         40         32
```

is there a way if I can have a subtotal for CA and a total total for both states in a row like above

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a view where the items are grouped by the state. This will cause each state to generate a sub total and in the header you'll see the full totals.